# I cannot run setInterval and another function at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, json, timer

I have two functions that are supposed to run when I click on a button. The first function is a setInterval function that increments the variable **num** by 0.01 and displays it in a div id called **result**. The second function generates an object literal into a json string and displays it in a div id called **output**. When I click on the button, only the JSON string is outputted, but it seems as though the setInterval doesn't run and I don't know why. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5ofcd4k2/) for example

HTML

```
<button>
click
</button>
<div id="result">

</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Javascript

```
var timer,
        result = document.getElementById("result"),
    num,
    link ={
     name:"link",
     weapon:"master sword",
     mute:true,
     race:"hyrulian",
     age:16
    };

/* ---------- GENERATE JSON OBJECT --*/
function generate(){
var data = {};
 for(var prop in link){
    data[prop] = link[prop];
 }
 data = JSON.stringify(data);
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
}

/* ---------- CLICK BUTTON --*/
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){

num = 0;
  function callBack(){
     num += 0.01;
   result.innerHTML = num.toFixed(2);

  }
  timer = setInterval(callBack,10);
  generate();
  clearInterval(timer);

}
```

Comment: You clear the interval before the function ends....................

Comment: I need the interval to be cleared once the generate function is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated My Answer:** You have to wrap your callBack(); function in the `setInterval` with an anonymous function. This is because `setInterval` expects a reference to a Function that should be executed every few milliseconds (the interval you specify). You should use it like this `setInterval( function(){ callBack(); }, 10);`. This should give you the desired result.

Same code, I just updated the `setInterval( function(){ callBack(); }, 10);` line:

```
var timer,
    result = document.getElementById("result"),
num,
link ={
 name:"link",
 weapon:"master sword",
 mute:true,
 race:"hyrulian",
 age:16
};

/* ---------- GENERATE JSON OBJECT --*/
function generate(){
var data = {};
for(var prop in link){
   data[prop] = link[prop];
}
data = JSON.stringify(data);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
}

/* ---------- CLICK BUTTON --*/
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){

num = 0;
  function callBack(){
 num += 0.01;
 result.innerHTML = num.toFixed(2);

 }
 timer = setInterval( function(){ callBack(); },10); // I modified this line
 // timer = setInterval(callBack,10);
 generate();
 clearInterval(timer);
 // setTimeout( function(){ clearInterval(timer); }, 1000); // This can be used to test that the timer has indeed started, you can wait 1 second before you clear the timer

 }
```

Comment: I need the interval to stop once the generate function has finished executing. Even if I put the clearInterval after generate or inside the function as the last statement. The interval doesn't run, how do I make the interval stop once the generator is done?

Comment: @black_yurizan, I guess you are trying to implement a stop watch. I have updated my code to reflex the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you `setInterval(callBack,10);`, but then you clear the interval using `clearInterval(timer);`.

remove the `clearInterval(timer);` and you'll get the timer working.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded.  In order for the `callBack` function which you have set up to run in an interval of 10ms with [`setInterval(callBack,10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to run, your JavaScript code has to *stop* running (i.e. complete).  Until your code relinquishes the processor, no call back functions (of any type) will execute.

Thus, in your code:

```
timer = setInterval(callBack,10);  //Set up the interval timer
generate();  //generate(): Even if this takes 10 minutes to complete
             //  the callBack function will not be executed from the interval timer.
clearInterval(timer); //Clear the interval timer. While the interval may have expired
                      //  (depending on how long the generate() function took), the 
                      //  the callBack function will have never run because the processor
                      //  has been busy continuing to run the code that came after calling 
                      //  setInterval.  Clearing the interval timer here results in 
                      //  callBack never being executed.
```

Thus, if you want `callBack` to execute even once, you need to *not* call [`clearInterval(timer)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) prior to the code you are executing at that time completing.

If you wanted `callBack` to only be executed once, then you could have used [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

### Timing how long something takes:

If you are attempting to time how long something takes:

1. Get the current time prior to what you are wanting to time

   - Use [`window.performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) which is "measured in milliseconds, accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond".
2. Do the thing you want to time
3. Get the time after you are done (Use [`window.performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) again).
4. Compute and display the difference between the two times.

So, modifying your code:

```js
var timer,
    result = document.getElementById("result"),
    link = {
        name: "link",
        weapon: "master sword",
        mute: true,
        race: "hyrulian",
        age: 16
    };

/* ---------- GENERATE JSON OBJECT --*/
function generate() {
    var data = {};
    for (var prop in link) {
      data[prop] = link[prop];
    }
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
}

/* ---------- CLICK BUTTON --*/
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    function showResult(time, precision, units) {
        result.innerHTML = time.toFixed(precision) + ' ' + units;
    }

    var startTime = window.performance.now();
    generate();
    var endTime = window.performance.now();
  
    //These times are floating point numbers in milliseconds
    var elapsedMs = endTime - startTime;
    showResult(elapsedMs,3,'milliseconds');

    //If you want to show the time in microseconds:
    //var elapsedUs = elapsedMs * 1000;
    //showResult(elapsedUs,0,'microseconds');
}
```

```html
<button>
  click
</button>
<div id="result">
</div>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

However, if your real goal is to determine how long, on average, it takes to run `generate()` then you need time how long it takes to run generate a large number of times, not just once.

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var link = {
        name: "link",
        weapon: "master sword",
        mute: true,
        race: "hyrulian",
        age: 16
    };

/* ---------- GENERATE JSON OBJECT --*/
function generate() {
    var data = {};
    for (var prop in link) {
      data[prop] = link[prop];
    }
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
}

/* ---------- CLICK BUTTON --*/
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(event) {
    //Should not do long things in an event handler.
    //Thus, instead of actually performing the tests here, we set
    //  a timeout which will execute after the event has processed.
    this.style.display = 'none'; //Only get to click once
    setTimeout(performTimedTests,0,generate,result);
}

/*
 * Perform multiple runs of an increasing number of iterations of a specified function.
 *   
 *   functionToTest = The function which is being timed
 *   resultsElement = An element in the DOM, usually a <div>, which will
 *                    have its innerHTML replaced with a table of time results.
 *   start =  The number of iterations to start with. (default = 1)
 *   end   =  The number of iterations to not exceed. (default = 1000000)
 *   multiplier = The amount multiply the current number of iterations to find
 *                  the number of iterations for the next run. (default = 10)
 */
function performTimedTests(functionToTest,resultsElement,start,end,multiplier){
    start=start?start:1;
    end=end?end:1000000;
    multiplier=multiplier?multiplier:10;
    var textColors =['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple']
    
    function timeAfunction(functionToTest, iterations){
        var i, startTime, endTime;
        startTime = window.performance.now();
        for(i=0;i<iterations;i++){
            functionToTest();
        }
        endTime = window.performance.now();
        return (endTime - startTime);
    }

    function addResultToTable(table, elapsedTime, iterations, precision1, units1
                              , precision2, units2, scale2, name) {
        var perCall = (elapsedTime/iterations)*scale2;
        var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
        newRow.insertCell(-1).textContent = iterations;
        newRow.insertCell(-1).textContent = elapsedTime.toFixed(precision1) + units1;
        newRow.insertCell(-1).textContent = perCall.toFixed(precision2) + units2;
        newRow.insertCell(-1).textContent = name;
    }


    function performNextTest(functionToTest,resultsElement,iterations,maxIterations
                             ,multiplier,isFirstIteration){
        var elapsedTime = timeAfunction(functionToTest, iterations);
        var processing;
        if(isFirstIteration) {
            result.innerHTML = '<div></div>'
                               +'<table><tr><th>Iterations</th><th>Total time</th>'
                               +'<th>Time per<br/>Iteration</th>'
                               +'<th>Function<br>Tested</th></tr></table>';
            processing = resultsElement.querySelector('div');
            processing.textContent = 'Processing';
            processing.style.color = textColors[0];
        }
        processing = resultsElement.querySelector('div');
        var table = resultsElement.querySelector('table');
        addResultToTable(table,elapsedTime,iterations,3,'ms',3,'us',1000
                         ,functionToTest.name);
        processing.textContent += '.';
        //Cycle colors of 'Processing..' text
        var colorIndex=textColors.indexOf(processing.style.color);
        colorIndex++;
        colorIndex = colorIndex>=textColors.length?0:colorIndex;
        processing.style.color = textColors[colorIndex];
        iterations *= multiplier;
        if(iterations<=maxIterations) {
            //Let the browser redraw
            setTimeout(performNextTest,0,functionToTest,resultsElement,iterations
                       ,maxIterations,multiplier,false);
        }else{
            processing.textContent = '';
            processing.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    performNextTest(functionToTest,resultsElement,start,end,multiplier,true);
}
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I need the timer to be cleared once  generate function is done. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @black_yurizan, The way you have this, it will never be run (as you know).  You can never have `callBack` run *at exactly the same time* as `generate`. Any callback function will *always* run either before, or after any other portion of JavaScript that is continuous (could run both before and after). Given your 10ms delay (a [*very* small amount of time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)), it appears that you should just go ahead and call `callBack` directly either before `generate()`, after `generate()`, or both.

Comment: @black_yurizan, In other words, using a interval timer, or a timeout (particularly with such a short delay) does not appear to be providing you with any benefit here (and appears is a sticking pint for getting your code to work). I'm not sure why you are setting up the interval timer for `callBack`.  What are you attempting to achieve with doing so?

Comment: @black_yurizan, Are you trying time how long it takes to run `generate()`?

Comment: "Are you trying time how long it takes to run generate()" - Yes

Comment: @black_yurizan, OK. Added functional code to time how long it takes to run `generate()`.

Comment: @black_yurizan, I added running `generate()` through multiple iterations to get a more accurate idea as to how long a single iteration actually takes.